# Testing service layer with repository pattern with xUnit, Moq in .NET Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, xunit

I am building a simple .NET Core Web Api application in which there is a background task that downloads some CSV files from a web site, save them into a DB (using EF Core). Another background tasks will take care of processing them.
This is just a demo application for me to familiarize with .NET Core Web Api, EF Core, Moq, xUnit and repository/service/unit of work pattern.

I have already written the business logic and it works fine, but now I want to have also tests.

This is the test I wrote in order to test the queueing functionality: it is very simple. I check if the file has already been queued (for a specific date), if not I queue it.

```
    [Fact]
    public void TestQueueFileForProcessingWhenNotYetQueued()
    {
        string alreadyQueuedFile = "Estrazione del 2019-01-02";
        var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        var gasStationExternalFileRepository = new Mock<IGasStationExternalFileRepository>();
        var service = new GasStationExternalFileService(mockUnitOfWork.Object, gasStationExternalFileRepository.Object);
        gasStationExternalFileRepository.Setup(x => x.HasFileAlreadyBeenQueued(new DateTime(2019, 01, 02))).Returns(false);

        var result = service.QueueFileForProcessing(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(alreadyQueuedFile));
        Assert.True(result, "Object has been queued now");

        var expectedFile = gasStationExternalFileRepository.Object.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ReferenceDate.Date == new DateTime(2019, 01, 02));
        Assert.NotNull(expectedFile);
        Assert.Equal(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(alreadyQueuedFile), expectedFile.Content);
        Assert.Null(expectedFile.ProcessingDate);
        Assert.Equal(Core.Reference.ProcessingStatus.Queued, expectedFile.ProcessingStatus);
        Assert.Equal(new DateTime(2019, 01, 02), expectedFile.ReferenceDate);
    }
```

And this is the underlying business logic :

```
     public class GasStationExternalFileService : IGasStationExternalFileService
        {
            public GasStationExternalFileService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IGasStationExternalFileRepository gasStationExternalFileRepository)
            {
                this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
                this.gasStationExternalFileRepository = gasStationExternalFileRepository;

            }

            readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
            readonly IGasStationExternalFileRepository gasStationExternalFileRepository;

            public bool QueueFileForProcessing(byte[] queue)
            {
                string fileContentAsText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(queue);
                var firstRow = fileContentAsText.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }).First();
                var referenceDate = DateTime.ParseExact(firstRow.Substring(15, 10), "yyyy-MM-dd", null);

                var alreadyQueued = gasStationExternalFileRepository.HasFileAlreadyBeenQueued(referenceDate);
                if (alreadyQueued)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    var file = new GasStationsExternalFile();
                    file.Content = queue;
                    file.ReferenceDate = referenceDate;
                    file.ProcessingStatus = Core.Reference.ProcessingStatus.Queued;
                    gasStationExternalFileRepository.Add(file);
                    unitOfWork.Complete();
                    return true;
                }
            }

            public void ProcessFile(Guid id)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

I'm expecting that expected file

```
        var expectedFile = gasStationExternalFileRepository.Object.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ReferenceDate.Date == new DateTime(2019, 01, 02));
```

is not null. But it is always null.

What am I missing?

EDIT: This is the subject under test

```
        public class GasStationExternalFileRepository : Repository<GasStationsExternalFile, DbContext>, IGasStationExternalFileRepository
        {
            public GasStationExternalFileRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
            {
            }

            public bool HasFileAlreadyBeenQueued(DateTime referenceDate)
            {
                return Entities.Where(x => x.ReferenceDate.Date == referenceDate).Select(x => x.Id).Any();
            }
        }


public abstract class Repository<TEntity, TContext> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    public Repository(TContext context)
    {
        Entities = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    protected DbSet<TEntity> Entities { get; }

    public TEntity Get(Guid id)
    {
        return Entities.Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return Entities.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Entities.Where(predicate);
    }

    public TEntity SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Entities.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        Entities.Add(entity);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        Entities.AddRange(entities);
    }

    public void Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
        Entities.Remove(entity);
    }

    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        Entities.RemoveRange(entities);
    }
}
```

Comment: `gasStationExternalFileRepository` is a Mock. It makes sense that the test returns null because it's not setup to contain any data. It also doesn't make sense to Test a Mocked object.

Comment: Show the subject under test and what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Please see last edits

Comment: What I want to achieve is: have the call to  gasStationExternalFileRepository.Object.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ReferenceDate.Date == new DateTime(2019, 01, 02)); return the object I added to it in my busines logic

Comment: You should only be testing methods/properties of `GasStationExternalFileService`. Your `gasStationExternalFileRepository` isn't a Repository, it's just a stubbed object to satisfy your Service's need for an `IGasStationExternalFileRepository`. Just assume `.Add(file)` works in you unit test because that's not what is being tested. The Repository implemenation should have it's own Unit Tests for that.

Comment: So you are saying that in this unit test I just need to test the "bool" result?

Comment: And furthermore...that I could test "both" behaviours implementing an Integration Test in which I don't mock the repository, but for example, I could use the SQLite in memory provider and simulate a real underlying repository?